# jquery sortable несколько connectwith

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

html

```
<div id="variants" class="sortvariants">
        <div id="ans_1"  class="variantions ui-state-error">Будапешт</div>
        <div id="ans_2"  class="variantions ui-state-error">Прага</div>

</div>

 <input type="text" id="newans"> <input type="button" id="appendb" value="Добавить">


  <div class="answer">
    <div id="current" class="title">Европа</div>
    <div id="flowerContainer" class="sortContainer">
      <div id="ans_4"  class="variantions ui-state-error">Каир</div>
    </div> 
 </div> 
   <div class="answer">
    <div id="current" class="title">Африка</div>
    <div id="flowerContainer2" class="sortContainer">
     <div id="ans_3"  class="variantions ui-state-error">Кельн</div>
    </div> 
 </div>
```

js

```
$(function() {

    $("#head").disableSelection();
    $('#variants').sortable({connectWith: '.sortContainer'});

    $( ".sortContainer" ).sortable({
        connectWith: '#variants',
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            $('#info').append(ui.item.attr("id"))
        },
        remove: function(event, ui) {
           var temp = $( "#info" ).text();
           $('#info').html(temp.replace(ui.item.attr("id"), " "))
        }
    });




  $("#appendb").click(function() {
    id = 4;
    $('#variants').append("<div id='ans_"+id+"'  class='variantions ui-state-error'>"+$( "#newans" ).val()+"</div>");
  });


});
```

Вот здесь пример - https://jsfiddle.net/morrowinds/kb18ncgm/15/

Проблема заключается в том что из "Африка" блоки в общую строку переносятся, а вот обратно нет. Обратно переносятся только в "Европа

Comment: проблемка в flowerContainer2

Comment: Ну это я понял, а какая проблема?=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в **CSS** отсутствует

```
#flowerContainer2 {  height: 80%; width: 140px; margin-left:13px; }
```

[Вот](https://jsfiddle.net/kb18ncgm/16/) рабочий вариант:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#head").disableSelection();
  $('#variants').sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortContainer'
  });

  $(".sortContainer").sortable({
    connectWith: '#variants',
    receive: function(event, ui) {
      $('#info').append(ui.item.attr("id"));
    },
    remove: function(event, ui) {
      var temp = $("#info").text();
      $('#info').html(temp.replace(ui.item.attr("id"), " "));
    }
  });




  $("#appendb").click(function() {
    id = 4;
    $('#variants').append("<div id='ans_" + id + "'  class='variantions ui-state-error'>" + $("#newans").val() + "</div>");
  });


});
```

```css
        div.sortable {
          width: 100px;
          background-color: lightgrey;
          font-size: large;
          margin: 4px;
          text-align: center;
          border: medium solid black;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        #fruitContainer {
          position: absolute;
          right: 50px;
        }
        #flowerContainer {
          height: 80%;
          width: 140px;
          margin-left: 13px;
        }
        #flowerContainer2 {
          height: 80%;
          width: 140px;
          margin-left: 13px;
        }
        div.flower {
          background-color: lightgreen
        }
        #info {
          float: right;
          border: padding: 4px;
          width: 10%;
        }
        .answer {
          background-color: #CFE2F3;
          width: 165px;
          height: 350px;
          border: medium solid black;
          margin-left: 28px;
          margin-top: 28px;
          border-radius: 17px;
          float: left;
        }
        div.title {
          width: 100px;
          margin: 5px auto;
          font-size: large;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        div.variantions {
          width: 100px;
          background-color: lightgrey;
          font-size: large;
          float: left;
          margin: 6px;
          text-align: center;
          border: medium solid black;
          padding: 10px;
        }
        .sortvariants {
          float: right;
          width: 50%;
        }
```

```html
<div id="variants" class="sortvariants">
  <div id="ans_1" class="variantions ui-state-error">Будапешт</div>
  <div id="ans_2" class="variantions ui-state-error">Прага</div>

</div>

<input type="text" id="newans">
<input type="button" id="appendb" value="Добавить">


<div class="answer">
  <div id="current" class="title">Европа</div>
  <div id="flowerContainer" class="sortContainer">
    <div id="ans_4" class="variantions ui-state-error">Каир</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="answer">
  <div id="current" class="title">Африка</div>
  <div id="flowerContainer2" class="sortContainer">
    <div id="ans_3" class="variantions ui-state-error">Кельн</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="info" class="ui-widget">

</div>
```

Comment: =)))) Точно, а я все мучаюсь! =)